# Why is margin box said to be box around all other boxes?

Tags: html, css, layout, dom

One thing i cant understand when it comes to elements boxes is the margin box.

For example mdn web docks defines it as follow :
"Margin box: The margin is the outermost layer, wrapping the content, padding, and border as whitespace between this box and other elements; size it using margin and related properties."

And most tutorials i found are inline with this definition. Saying margin box is box around all other boxes wrapping them up that we then generally use to make space between elements.

But then what really confuses me is how is it that we can set margin to be negative and make elements overlap in that way if its a box that is around and wraps up other elements boxes namely content,padding,border box?

It doesn't make sense to me. To me it only makes sense to say that dimensions of margin box in initially based on dimensions of other elements boxes not that it wraps up other boxes or anything as often defined. I cant see how it can wrap other boxes if we can set it to be negative size and make it smaller than all other boxes while they all remain the same size just so we can overlap different elements.

Now padding box for example is defined as box around content box wrapping it up and therefore we cant set it to negative size since it wouldn't make sense then. But thats not the case with margin box at all.

Wouldn't be more accurate to say that its completely separate thing, like a box that works as invisible field which dictates how given box will interact with other boxes in overall layout? I dont see any relation between it or any other elements boxes aside from them defining initially its dimensions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The same answer as @Steve but added a image of the box model.

I can relate to your semantic objections, but also other types of boxes takes space. Regardless what you call them.

At the beginning I did not realized that even the border increased the size of the box in some cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because a margin (and padding, and some other elements) is made up of 4 separate parts: top, bottom, left and right.

When you state `margin:10px` that is the same as saying

```
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
```

Once you see that, then you it should make sense that you can have different values for each side and some of them can be negative.